# Issue excluding source folder in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to exclude from the build process an entire folder in eclipse but the IDE is still showing compiler errors for those files. This is in eclipse indigo.

I tried excluding both the folder and one of the files individually:

[image]

But I'm still seeing compiler errors:

[image]

Comment: Seems weird you have output folder same as your source, I think this may mess things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as I tried to run the application once, the build errors went away. I think this forced a rebuild of the project which the caused eclipse to recognize the new build settings.